# Як грамотно перекласти "media proxy"?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

Намагаюся локалізувати Pleroma (https://git.pleroma.social/pleroma/pleroma-fe).
Це словосполучення вживається на позначення особливості (feature) поточного серверу, де встановлена ця програма, і означає те, що даний сервер грає роль прошарку (проксі) для медіа-файлів, які надходять з інших серверів та показуються у стрічці новин. Зокрема, поточний сервер кешує ці файли, і, коли вони змінюються на серверах-джерелах, оновлює їхню копію у себе вдома.

Я думаю перекласти це як "медіа-прошарок", але воно, на перший погляд, не звучить зрозумілим.
"медіа-проксі" - занадто англомовне, але поки що я переклав саме так (краще, ніж ніяк).
Що ви скажете з приводу "медіа-посередник"?

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості вимагають, щоб запитання про переклад містило: (1) пояснення **своїми словами** іншомовного слова; (2) **контекст**, в якому автор збирається використовувати перекладене слово; (3) продемонструвати власну спробу знайти відповідь і (4) пояснити, чим са́ме знайдені варіанти не підходять. Запитання, які не відповідають цим умовам, змушують інших «вгадувати», чого саме хоче автор, і тому заважають надавати точні відповіді.

Comment: Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [ask] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні запитання і відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/).

Comment: @MichaelMichael, можете пояснити, що саме означає цей термін?

Comment: @Sasha на жаль, ще ні. Я погарячкував з цим дописом, хотілось локалізувати цю програму нахрапом, без нудного встановлення та виснажливих налаштувань, чи можливо видалити цей допис, або, принаймні, приховати його?

Comment: Є посилання «delete» під запитанням (над коментарями до нього) (це не остаточне видалення, потім, якщо передумаєте чи дістанете більше контексту, зможете зробити «undelete»).

Comment: тобто проксі оновлює файли у себе навіть без запиту від користувача? тобто, якщо користувачі цей файл більше ніколи не запитають, то він даремно ганяв біти мережею?

Comment: Те що ви описали звучить як *буфер*.

Comment: Якщо я правильно зрозумів — це налаштування програми, що визначає, чи треба проксіювати медійні файли, чи не треба (тобто це налаштування може приймати по суті два значення: «так» і «ні») — чи я правильно зрозумів?

Comment: @Sasha Я не знаю, чи можна це налаштувати (так/ні), але це точно є властивістю, особливістю сервера, ось приклад, де його можна побачити у лівому нижньому кутку: https://miniwa.moe/main/all

А ось приклад його значення: https://social.net.ua/notice/466
Тут бот - з іншого сервера (наведіть на його аватарку), але його світлина - вже з нашого (наведіть на дописану ним світлину), тобто, наш сервер віддає його світлину, яку він у себе дописав. Моя особиста думка - для того, щоб не перевантажувати оригінальний сервер з популярними користувачами. Справді, звучить як кеш, але в оригіналі - proxy.

Answer (score 6):

Скоріше за все цей термін не перекладається, а українською мовою буде **"медіа-проксі"**.
Аргументую тим, що саме слово "проксі" не перекладається. Так само й інші подібні терміни, наприклад:
- інтернет
- вай-фай
- блютус тощо.

Comment: Як на мене, слово "медіа" пустило глибші корені, ніж "проксі", тому хотілося би "проксі" зукраїнізувати, доки не вросло. Якої ви думки про "медіа-прошарок" чи "медіа-посередник"?

Comment: Спочатку надайте визначення терміну проксі, щоб зрозуміти що українізувати його - це марна справа.

Comment: Найцікавіше те (з власного досвіду), що переклад відсутній в рідких вийняткових випадках. Порівняння з Wi-Fi нелогічне. Інтернет та bluetooth - перекладаються. Якщо брати повні слова від Wi-Fi, то можна знайти переклад.

Comment: от вам приклад чи не найкращого в світі медіапроксі https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/

Comment: і визначення https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy

Answer (score 4):

Наскільки я розумію, це якась конфігурація цієї програми, що може мати одне з двох значент — «так» або «ні».

Тоді я пропоную такі варіанти перекладу:

- проксіювати медійні дані
- проксіювати медійні файли
- проксіювати медіа-дані
- проксіювати медіа-файли
- виступати посередником для медійних даних
- виступати посередником для медійних файлів
- виступати посередником для медіа-даних
- виступати посередником для медіа-файлів

Comment: Дякую, усі варіанти дуже довгі, мені більше імпонує "Посередник медіа-даних", без наказового способу.

Answer (score 2):

Тип проксі, який ви описали це **кеш**.

Але при перекладі треба врахувати такий момент, що коли користувач шукатиме відповідь на своє питання в інтернеті. то дуже імовірно він його знайде англійською, тому бажано, щоб різниця між українським і англійськими відповідниками не була надто великою, тобто варто робити дослівні переклади.

Виходячи з попереднього абзацу, можна перекласти як **медіа-проксі** або, якщо там достатньо місця, то **медіа-проксі (кеш)**. (Хоча, звісно, українськості це не додає.)

Comment: Так, схоже більше на кеш, але в оригіналі саме "proxy".
А якої ви думки про "медіа-прошарок" чи "медіа-посередник"?

Comment: @MichaelMichael Гадаю, що *прошарок* тут може бути недоречним, тому що для мене *прошарок* більше асоціюється з *layer*, як-от в *multi-layered application*.

Answer (score 0):

Media proxy - Представлення посередників.

Media - посередники. [plural form of medium](https://www.lexico.com/definition/media), в значенні [файлів посередників](https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/multimedia-file).

Medium - [в значенні посередника](https://www.lexico.com/definition/medium).

Proxy - [в значенні представника (представництва, представлення чогось).](https://www.lexico.com/definition/proxy)

Proxy - в значенні [замісника](https://refactoring.guru/uk/design-patterns/proxy).

Comment: Proxy може бути в значенні як посередника, так і представника. У цьому контексті media не значить посередники, це мультимедійні файли.

Comment: @Vlad26t Що означає multimedia? Чому multi? І чому саме media? Як це пов'язано з mass media? До чого тут ЗМі? Чи є зв'язок ЗМІ з media? Який цей зв'язок? І чому файли саме multimedia, а не інформаційні, наприклад. Чи ще якісь?

Comment: Ось чому нам так важко все зрозуміти. Бо ми приносимо іноземні вузькі значення і без розуміння самих слів, хоча подібні слова вже є в нашій мові. Просто мало хто  намагається зрозуміти їх. Багаж знань не дозволяє правильно використовувати наші відповідники на місці такого ж іноземного. А коли дозволяє багаж знань, то відповідно і для proxy знаходиться найточніший відповідник замісник. Відповідно коли розумієш, що media - це посередники, то й по іншому починаєш розуміти професію журналіста. Ніколи про це так не думав.

Comment: @Vlad26t Коли ви говорите про файли, то краще використовувати слово files. Бо слово media без files не вказує на значення files. А зосереджує увагу лише на media.